# how can i use max()/min() as css-math-functions instead of stylus-bulidin-functions

Tags: css, stylus

such as

```
.some-class
  position absolute
  left max(0px, 20vh - 100px)
```

my intention was calling https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max

but due to http://stylus-lang.com/docs/bifs.html#mina-b, in this case, the 'left' will always be '0px'

how can i solve it?

Comment: [CSS Literal](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/literal.html), maybe?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález you are right, helpful!

Answer (score 5):

I found this slightly hacky solution that seems to work:

```
max-width: "min(60vh, 580px)" % null;
```

Basically you're using this syntax that normally is used to apply a variable to a string, but you're replacing nothing with nothing, so it resolves to the actual rule you want.

Comment: `max-width: "min(%s)" %  (60vh, 580px)`

Answer (score 5):

As discussed [here](https://github.com/stylus/stylus/issues/2584), the current best workaround is `@css{}`:

```css
left @css{max(0px, 20vh - 100px)}
```